# Using textbox in limit sql query

Tags: sql, mysql, vb.net

Normally I've been using these statement and it works :

```
"SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 10"
```

And I've tried this but it has errors saying error in sql syntax

```
"SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT '" + TextBox1.Text + "' "
```

Comment: besides single quotes that you don't need vb net uses & for string concatenation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how the first statement, which works, has no quotes and the second one, which does not work, does? You need to follow the pattern of the first one.

*However*, you need to parse TextBox1.Text into an integer and concatenate that into the string to prevent SQL injection attacks, so...

```
Dim lim = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM [tablename] LIMIT " & lim
```

You may want to use [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) instead to check a valid number was supplied.

(Also, the string concatenation operator in VB.NET is `&`, not `+`.)

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have edited my post. Tho regarding the code you pasted i tried to use it. Though I'm getting this error.  "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'"

Comment: @EdisonBalangueFeraro That error message means that it could not parse TextBox1.Text as an integer. What was in that textbox?

Comment: I got it bro.   So the value of the textbox is coming from database. So my arrangement of codes is in form load. The code above is in the 1st line of code and the fetching data from the database into the textbox is bellow it. So when the form loads, it loads 1st the code above. Because the textbox default value has nothing on it. I got the  "Input string was not in a correct format" error.

Comment: @EdisonBalangueFeraro In that case, tt would be better not to use the TextBox to store the value - just use a normal variable to store it. Of course, you can still show the value in a TextBox, if that is useful to the user.